# What is the default video pixel resolution for the IPhone 5?

Tags: ios, iphone, uiimagepickercontroller

I am using UIImagePickerController to load the video camera but I would like the resolution to match the default camera app resolution on the IPhone.

I know the default for the 4S is

```
UIImagePickerControllerQualityTypeIFrame1280x720
```

Does anyone have the info for the other models?

Thanks

Comment: http://www.iphoneresolution.com/

Comment: Sorry that is the screen resolution. I am looking for the pixel dimensions that the default camera films in.

Comment: For iOS above 5.0: **UIImagePickerControllerQualityTypeIFrame960x540 = 5**